# How to replace same string with new Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm new in coredata, and I don't understand few things.

I'm trying to make web browser history. And if I save in `webviewdidFinishLoad` string webpage title and url, it does it well. But if I visit in same page again, it saves same title and url again. I want something that replace old string with new. Like it happens in SQLite - if I write "TEXT UNIQUE".

It's probably is wierd question, but I can't find anything useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of Core Data is not a SQL data base, it just makes it easy to persist and handle related objects. You will need to write code to fetch the entire entries persisted and then have a `for` loop or `NSPredicate` to check the uniqueness and then persist if not already present.